# Neo4j : create relationship between two or more nodes having the same Label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a csv file containing activities (process graph) :

```
startActivityId,Name,endActivityId
 1,A,2
 2,B,3
 3,C,4
 4,D,5
```

so that it will look like this : A->B->C->D
i imported the csv file successfully into neo4j server : using this Cypher query :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:path/graph/activity.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Activity {startactivityId:row.startActivityId, Name: row.Name, endActivityId: row.endActivityId});
```

i then created an index on startactivityId :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :activity(startActivityId);
```

then i want to create the relationships between these nodes, so tried this cypher query :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:path/graph/activity.csv" AS row
MATCH (startActivity:Activity {startActivityId: row.startActivityId})
MATCH (endActivity:Activity {startActivityId: row.endActivityId})
MERGE (startActivity)-[:LINKS_TO]->(endActivity);`
```

but no relationships created, nothing happens

i'm sure i missed something cause i'm new to cypher but i can't figure it out.

any ideas ?

Comment: You have mixed uppercase/lowercase in your csv and queries, for instance `startActivityId` in the csv but `row.startactivityId` in the query, and node property `startactivityId` in the create query but `startActivityId` in the match. Does it work if you fix that?

Comment: no i made the mistake here when i wrote this question, but in the cypher code it's correct,

Comment: is the structure of my query correct ?

Comment: Is that what your csv file actually looks like or did you align it just for posting here? Because if that's what your file looks like then your property values will have a bunch of blank spaces in them, and with the spaces there are no matching `startActivityId` and `endActivityId`. What does `MATCH (n:Activity) RETURN n` tell you?

Comment: no i just aligned to look more readable here, there is no blank spaces

Comment: the MATCH (n:Activity) RETURN n  shows the four nodes without the relationships

Comment: I'm with @jjaderberg the way you've formulated your question  makes it difficult to tell if there's a trivial capitalization of space padding issue.  I would suggest posting your actual query and actual data, don't try to clean it up, that would let us see what you're really running against.  On your MATCH MATCH MERGE query, you might try OPTIONAL MATCH OPTIONAL MATCH then return count(startActivity), count(endActivity) to see which match is failing, to help you narrow down

Comment: so i edited the question, this is what it looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your updated csv (and removed the whitespace at the head of the first column) and ran your queries.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/jonatan/src/doc/stackexchange/32225817.pdc" as row CREATE (:Activity {startActivityId:row.startActivityId, name:row.Name, endActivityId:row.endActivityId});                                            
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 4
Properties set: 12
Labels added: 4
115 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/jonatan/src/doc/stackexchange/32225817.pdc" as row MATCH (s:Activity {startActivityId:row.startActivityId}) MATCH (e:Activity {startActivityId:row.endActivityId}) MERGE (s)-[r:LINKS_TO]->(e) RETURN r;
+-------------------+
| r                 |
+-------------------+
| :LINKS_TO[2084]{} |
| :LINKS_TO[2085]{} |
| :LINKS_TO[2086]{} |
+-------------------+
3 rows
Relationships created: 3
178 ms
```

Three relationships created. To confirm that they are the right relationships I match and return the path `(:Activity)-[:LINKS_TO]->()`.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH p=(:Activity)-[:LINKS_TO]->() RETURN p;         
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p                                                                                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [Node[1415]{name:"A",startActivityId:"1",endActivityId:"2"},:LINKS_TO[2084]{},Node[1416]{name:"B",startActivityId:"2",endActivityId:"3"}] |
| [Node[1416]{name:"B",startActivityId:"2",endActivityId:"3"},:LINKS_TO[2085]{},Node[1417]{name:"C",startActivityId:"3",endActivityId:"4"}] |
| [Node[1417]{name:"C",startActivityId:"3",endActivityId:"4"},:LINKS_TO[2086]{},Node[1418]{name:"D",startActivityId:"4",endActivityId:"5"}] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows
49 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

It looks OK to me, not sure what's not working for you.

What does `MATCH p=(:Activity)-[r]->() RETURN p;` tell you?

Comment: hey, just one question, sometimes i don't get the name inside that circle ( neo4j server admin tool ) in the representation, how can i select one property to appear inside the circle ?